# SQL-server good way to create Dictionary table

Tags: sql-server, database, dictionary, database-design

Anyway to create Dictionary database in SQLserver
that consist word and definition and word type (Verb,Noun,etc.)?

Just contain all data in one table
or do something like hash-table

table A contain only word that start with 'A'
table B contain only word that start with 'B'

I'm very new in Databases.

Comment: Generally, you don't split data into different tables based on attribute values (because for general querying, you might want data from *any* of the tables for any particular query). Also, how do you want to deal with homonyms?

Answer (score 2):

All in one table, always. Never ever design a database where one needs to dynamically name objects ('to lookup key 'foo', use 'table6522'). Dynamic naming is a recipe for disaster, performance wise and development wise, and you'll just self-inflict a **lot** of pain when it comes to use tools.

If you *must* partition the table, SQL Server already has [partitioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx), but this does not apply to you case (hint, unless you are a DBA designing an ETL pipeline with fast partition switching, partitioning is **never** an answer). See [SQL Server Partitioning: Not the Best Practices for Everything](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/06/sql-server-partitioning-not-the-answer-to-everything/) for more details.

A good way to design *any* table in SQL Server is to choose a correct clustered index and add appropriate indexes **for you specific workload**. The design is driven by how you are going to query the table. Read carefully [SQL Server Index Design Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx). When you're done, read it again. Then again. Repeat this for the next 4-5 days until you really grok what's being said there.